# WCF restful service injecting WebOperationContext with Autofac

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

I have been working on .net 4.0 webapi restful service project. In that project in one the of object we would like to inject WebOberationContext.Current dynamically. Is there any way to achieve this using Autofac. I googled a lot, but haven't found a solution, yet. For the time being i am using the following code:

```
public class SomeObject : ISomeObject
{
     private readonly ISomeService _someService;
     public SomeObject(ISomeService someService)
     {
        _someService = someService;
     }

     public WebOperationContext Context { get; set; }

     public void SomeOperation()
     {
          var incomeRequtests = Context.Current.IncomingRequests;
     }
}
```

Rather than set WebOperationContext as property, i want to find out, if we can auto inject it using autofac.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious - why do you need to inject the context? Are you mocking it for testing or something?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the context. This is one often-complained problems with WCF, the lack of "unit-testability" (especially things such as the WebOperationContext or the OperationContext). The new WCF Web APIs (from http://wcf.codeplex.com) are a good first step towards fixing this problem.